# Не удается пересобрать проект ASP.NET после отладки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2017, asp

Использую MS Visual Studio 2017 Community для написания ASP.NET приложения. После того, как решение было собрано и запущено на отладку один раз, больше не пересобирается. Очистка решения, пересборка приводят к ошибкам.

```
не удалось скопировать файл "D:\USERS\PAVEL\PROJECTS\WebApplication2\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\tools\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" в "bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll". Отказано в доступе по пути "bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll".
```

И таких еще 7 штук для разных файлов.
Отладку останавливаю из VS "Отадка" -> "Остановить отладку".
Иногда после отладки в трее висит значок IIS Express. На него жму правой кнопкой мыши, выбираю сайт, который только что запускался, и останавливаю.
Даже после этого доступа на запись к файлам нет.
Перезапуск студии не помогает. Помогает только перезагрузка компьютера.

В гугле был, но ничего не нашел. Если я плохо искал, прошу извинить и ткнуть меня носом в ссылку. Спасибо.

**UPD:** Запуск от администратора (правый клик на ярлыке vs -> Запуск от имени администратора) не помогает.

**Решение:** убить в диспетчере процесс VBCSCompiler.exe решает проблему. После останова процесса, пересборка идет нормально.

Comment: Отказано в доступе - нет прав. Попробуйте от администратора студию запустить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не помогает

Comment: Вот что нашел "...In order to clear the issue I have to stop the VBCSCompiler.exe task and then rebuild the solution..."

Comment: @АртёмОконечников спасибо! Помогло.